# how to reference the other sheet in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**sheet1** have some data as the following:

```
      A          B         C             D
    1 number    name     unit         price

    2  1001      apple    box           20.00   

    3 1002        peach   box          10.00  

  ..................
```

now on the **sheet2**

```
      A          B         C             D
    1 number    name     unit         price

    2  1001              

    3  

  ..................
```

now,  if i type `1001` in `A2` cell, i want the `apple,box,20.00` can auto typed into the cells.thank you.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming whatsoever. Should be posted on SuperUser, not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your range in sheet1 is a1:d3, in sheet2 cell b2 you have to type

```
=CERCA.VERT(A2;Foglio1!$A$1:$D$3;2;FALSO)
```

in cell b3

```
=CERCA.VERT(A2;Foglio1!$A$1:$D$3;3;FALSO)
```

and in cell b4

```
=CERCA.VERT(A2;Foglio1!$A$1:$D$3;4;FALSO)
```

These are italian formulas.

I think that in english version it becomes something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$3,2,FALSE)
```

and so on for the other cells.

Comment: what's these perameters meaning? !$A$1:$D$3,2,FALSE

Comment: $A$1:$D$3 as I already wrote you is the range of sheet1 based on your example, 2 is the column index of the value you're looking for and false means that you want an exact match. By the way excel has a useful online guide and google is your friend once you know what you have to search. :) edit. Explanation found with google: http://www.contextures.com/xlfunctions02.html

Comment: i am sorry, i am a newbie of excel. when i put the =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$3,2,FALSE) into A2 on sheet2. it can't auto typed apple    box  ...how to use your code? thank you

Comment: You have to put the formula in cell b2 of sheet2. if you type 1001 in cella a2 you'll get apple, if you type 1002 the formula will get you peach. Repeat the formula changing index column (3 and 4) for the other two values you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In cell B1

```
=If(IsError(Vlookup(A1, Sheet2!A:D, 2, false), "", Vlookup(A1, Sheet2!A:D, 2, false))
```

In Cell C1

```
=If(IsError(Vlookup(A1, Sheet2!A:D, 3, false), "", Vlookup(A1, Sheet2!A:D, 3, false))
```

In Cell D1

```
=If(IsError(Vlookup(A1, Sheet2!A:D, 4, false), "", Vlookup(A1, Sheet2!A:D, 4, false))
```